# lightning:icon not lightning:button with iconName attribute is not displaying

Tags: lightning-aura-components, svg-icon

Tried in all browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox) - but the icon is not displayed and I'm getting the following error message in the console:

> Unknown token "lightning.utilitySprite" default value was used instead.

This is the code I'm using:

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css'}"/>
    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:add" size="large" alternativeText="sss"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Download" iconName="utility:add" iconPosition="left" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: We do not see your code.

Comment: The code is there, it is just a formatting issue, which I corrected in a suggested edit. As soon as my edit has been approved, the code will be visible.

Comment: `<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css'}"/>`: This part is not required anymore. It is defaulty loaded by SF in your lightning component.

Comment: There may be styling issue. I have seen that problem in my project, too. When I investigate, I see that there is an icon but its color white as in background. So it is invisible. When I change style by adding `fill: #223344` icon has been visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running the component in a standalone app(i.e customAppName.app), then you need to add `extends="force:slds"` to you custom aura:application only then the icon will be displayed.

Eg:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
   <lightning:icon iconName="utility:add" size="large" alternativeText="sss"/>
</aura>
```

If the component runs inside LEX/SF1, it will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
<aura:component >
    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:add" size="large" alternativeText="sss"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Download" iconName="utility:add" iconPosition="left" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
</aura:component>
```

This works perfectly without:

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css'}"/>
```

The `slds` is loaded by default. I think there was a conflict about icons.

Comment: When I am not using <ltng:require ..... >, the button is displayed without any styles in it. Full page button with the same error: Unknown token "lightning.utilitySprite" default value was used instead.